# How to specify servlet in the action attribute of a <form>?

Tags: java, jsp

I have a form in jsp file that is processed in a servlet

The servlet looks like this

```
@WebServlet("/hello")
public class Test extends HttpServlet 
    //////////////
```

The jsp file looks like this

```
<form action="/Project/hello" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form "/>
 </form>
```

---

I need this servlet to forward request to a different jsp 
So i modify this code as

```
// I remove @WebService  The Test class is in the test folder
public class Test extends HttpServlet 
    ////////////// 
 forward  blah blah


<form action="/test/Test" method="GET">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit form "/>
```

And i get 404

How can I specify my servlet in the action attribute of the form ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to map the servlet with url in web.xml like below

```
<servlet>
 <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
 <servlet-class>com.company.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
 <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
 <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Then you need to give the url in the form action as below:

```
<form action="test" method="get">
```

your method in servlet(doGet or doPost) should match the method that you are specifying in your jsp.

Comment: THank you , however i am a little confused about this line `<servlet-class>com.company.Test</servlet-class>` . Since my Test servlet is in the test folder , I used `<servlet-class>test.Test</servlet-class> ` is it correct ?

Comment: com.company.Test  here com.company is the package where Test servlet is in.
In you case,if test is your package folder then test.Test is correct one.

Answer (score 1):

Map it in `web.xml` on an `<url-pattern>` like `/test`.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.Test</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And in your jsp, form action point to this URL.

```
<form action="test"/>
```

Comment: Thank you  . Since my Test servlet is in the test folder , I used `<servlet-class>test.Test</servlet-class> ` and got 404 . What is the correct way

Comment: You should add your package name. Where is test folder in your code base?

Answer (score 1):

```
@WebService("/test/Test")
public class Test extends HttpServlet
```

You need the annotation to map the servlet to a url or an entry for the servlet in your web.xml

Comment: How do i refer i tried  `<form action="/test/Test"/>` it did not work